# Running Angular CLI on Windows 7 on Office Network

Tags: windows, angular, angular-cli

I work for a large company with its own network, firewall, etc. I want to start learning Angular but I can't use Angular CLI to start a project. My company computer is a Windows 7 laptop.  I tried:

`ng new test-app`

but I got the result in this screen cap:
[image: screen capture]

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to resolve this so I can run `ng new` commands?

It seems to be an issue of dependencies but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: The message output shows *exactly* what you need to do. Install the CLI globally using `npm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a previous install of NPM with odd settings for a particular project.  I found instructions online to completely remove all traces of NPM on my computer.  Then I did a fresh install and things are working now.